# permutations of N balls in M boxes in C++

Tags: c++, python, permutation

I asked a question last week about permutations in C++ ([List of combinations of N balls in M boxes in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508365/list-of-combinations-of-n-balls-in-m-boxes-in-c)).

The answers have helped me a lot but my problem has now changed.
What i would like to do is a translation from this python function to C++, keeping the same order in the result :

```py
def combinations_with_replacement_counts(n, r):  #(n-boxes, r-balls)
   size = n + r - 1
   for indices in itertools.combinations(range(size), n-1):
       #print indices
       starts = [0] + [index+1 for index in indices]
       stops = indices + (size,)
       yield tuple(map(operator.sub, stops, starts))
```

I've no skill in python and despite my readings of the doc, I don't understand this function.

Comment: What specific parts don't you understand?

Comment: I don't understand the itertools.combinations() algorithm and the syntax of "stops = indices + (size,)". Concerning map(), does it subtract elements of starts and stop like stops[i] - starts[i] or stops[1] - stops[2]... and starts[1] - starts[2] separately ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This C++ code seems to have the same results as your python sample. It is far from the perfect one, still you could understand the algorithm and even use this implementation.

```
#include <deque>
typedef std::deque<size_t> BoxList;

class Generator {
    size_t boxNum, ballNum, ownBox;
    Generator* recursive;
public:
    ~Generator() { if ( recursive == NULL ) delete recursive; }
    Generator( size_t boxes, size_t balls ) : boxNum(boxes), ballNum(balls) {
        if ( boxes > 1 ) {
            recursive = new Generator( boxes-1, balls );
            ownBox = 0;
        } else {
            recursive = NULL;
            ownBox = balls;
        }
    }
    BoxList operator()() {
        if ( ownBox > ballNum ) throw 1;
        if ( boxNum <= 1 ) return BoxList( 1, ownBox++ );
        try {
            BoxList res = recursive->operator()(); 
            res.push_front( ownBox );
            return res;
        }
        catch(...) {
            delete recursive;
            ownBox++;
            recursive = new Generator( boxNum-1, ballNum-ownBox );
            return operator()();
        }
    }
};
```

Class interface allows you to use it as a standard generator. Operator () will generate exception when all possible options have been already iterated.

```
Generator g( boxes, balls );
try{
    while( true )
        g();
}
catch(...) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

You know python is interpreted, right?  You can just type the lines you don't understand directly into python and see what happens ... start with small values first.

> I don't understand the itertools.combinations() algorithm

The documentation is [here](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), and includes example output.
Note that the value returned from `combinations` is lazy, so you need to force evaluation to see it:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> itertools.combinations(range(4), 2)
<itertools.combinations object at 0x979a964>
>>> list(itertools.combinations(range(4), 2))
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Is it clear what `combinations` does now?  If not, have a play with it.

> ... and the syntax of "stops = indices + (size,)"

So *try* it, it won't bite:

```
>>> indices=list(itertools.combinations(range(4), 2))[0]
>>> size=4
>>> stops=indices + (size,)
>>> indices
(0, 1)
>>> stops
(0, 1, 4)
```

The syntax `(x,)` creates a one-element tuple (an invariant sequence - just like a `list` you can't change but with round parentheses `()` instead of square ones `[]`).  You can use `[x]` to create a one-element list, but `(x)` would be ambiguous since round parentheses are also used for other things, like function arguments and grouping.

> Concerning map(), ...

Read the [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map), have a play with it, it isn't hard.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Concerning combinations() that's not the result but the algorithm itself that i don't understand. I had a good play with the other things :)

Comment: @eryksun, thanks for that - I'd forgotten about using the comma in isolation

Answer (score 0):

The Python code you quoted is implementing the algorithm I described in [my answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508365/list-of-combinations-of-n-balls-in-m-boxes-in-c/6609080#6609080): it's iterating over the possible ways to place *r* − 1 boxes in *n* + *r* − 1 positions, and then making a list of the differences between adjacent positions (which count the number of balls that are swept into that box).